# How to I design a database constraint so two entities can only have a many to many relationship if two field values within them match?

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many, relationship

I have a database with four tables as follows:

**Addressbook**
--------------------
*id* 
more fields

**Contact**
---------------------
*id*
addressbook id
more fields

**Group**
---------------------
*id*
addressbook id
more fields

**Group to Contact**
---------------------
*Composite key*
Group id
Contact id

My relationships are one to many for addressbook > contact, one to many for addressbook > group and many to many between contact and groups.

So in summary, I have an addressbook.  Contacts and groups can be stored within it and they cannot be stored in more than one addressbook.  Furthermore as many contacts that are needed can be added to as many groups as are needed.

My question now poses as follows.  I wish to add the constraint that *a contact can only be a member of a group if both of them have the same addressbook id*.

As I am not a database person this is boggling my brain.  Does this mean I have designed my table structure wrong?  Or does this mean that I have to add a check somewhere before inserting into the group to contact table?  This seems wrong to me because I would want it to be impossible for SQL queries to link contacts to groups if they do not have the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by adding a **addressbook_id** column to your **Group to Contact** bridge table, then using a compound foreign key to both the **Contacts** and **Groups** tables.

In PostgreSQL (but easily adaptable to any DB, or at least any DB that supports compound FKs):

```
CREATE TABLE group_to_contact (
    contact_id          INT,
    group_id            INT,
    addressbook_id      INT,
    CONSTRAINT contact_fk FOREIGN KEY (contact_id,addressbook_id)
        REFERENCES contacts(id,addressbook_id),
    CONSTRAINT groups_fk FOREIGN KEY (group_id,addressbook_id)
        REFERENCES groups(id,addressbook_id)
)
```

By using the same **addressbook_id** column in both constraints, you are of course enforcing that they are the same in both referenced tables.

Comment: In most database systems, you need to declare `(id,addressbook_id)` as an additional unique constraint in the target tables (`contacts` and `groups`) in order that the foreign key constraint can reference them.

Comment: @Damien: Since `Group(id)` is primary key (and thus unique), is that really necessary?

Comment: @ypercube: Whether it's necessary likely depends on your DB engine. In most cases, it's probably _advisable_, as having both sides of a FK relationship fully indexed will usually improve performance, even if it's not strictly required by your DB engine.

Comment: @Flimzy: You are right about performance. I wasn't asking about an `index` but about a `unique constraint` on `Group(id,addressbook_id)`

Comment: Ah, well, in PostgreSQL, unique constraints *are* indexes, so I was thinking of them as one and the same.  Although they aren't necessarily the same everywhere. I'm sorry I can't answer that question more directly for other DB engines.

Comment: @ypercube - for SQL Server, the referenced columns have to be in a unique index (PK, unique constraint, or just index). For MySQL, I believe the same constraints apply (that the referenced columns must be in an index)

Comment: @Flimzy: You're on the right track, but you didn't get it completely right. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

OK - the Many to Many is governed by the GroupToContact table.

So the constraints are between Group and GroupToContact and between Contact and GroupToContact (GTC)

Namely

```
 [Group].groupId = GTC.GroupId AND [Group].AddressBookid = GTC.AddressBookId
```

And

```
Contact.ContactId = GTC.ContactID AND Contact.AddressBookId = GTC.AddressBookId
```

So you will need to add AddressBookId to GroupToContact table

One further note - you should not define any relationship between Contact and Group directly - instead you just define the OneToMany relationships each has with the GroupToContact table.

Answer (score 1):

As A CHECK Constraint can't include sub-queries.
You could create a trigger that checks that the group and contact have the same addressbookid
and generate an error if they do not.

Although a database trigger defined to enforce an integrity rule does not check the data already in the table, I would recommended that you use a trigger only when the integrity rule cannot be enforced by an integrity constraint.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Group_to_Contact_InsertOrUpdate on Group_to_Contact
FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
IF (SELECT Count(*) FROM inserted i 
 INNER JOIN Group g   ON i.groupid= g.groupid AND a.addressbookid=i.addressbookid
 INNER JOIN Address a ON a.addressbookid=I.addressbookid AND a.addressd=i.addressid) = 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Address Book Mismatch', 16, 1)
    rollback tran
END
```

Note:(This is from memory so probably not syntactically correct)

Answer (score 1):

As BonyT suggestion:

```
  Addressbook    
---------------  
*id*  
...more fields  
PRIMARY KEY (id)      

  Contact    
-----------  
*id*  
addressbook_id   
...more fields  
PRIMARY KEY (id)  
FOREIGN KEY (addressbook_id)  
    REFERENCES Addressbook(id)

  Group  
---------
*id*  
addressbook_id  
...more fields  
PRIMARY KEY (id)  
FOREIGN KEY (addressbook_id)
    REFERENCES Addressbook(id)

  Group to Contact    
--------------------   
*group_id*  
*contact_id*  
addressbook_id  
PRIMARY KEY (group_id, contact_id)  
FOREIGN KEY (addressbook_id, contact_id)  
    REFERENCES Contact(addressbook, id)
FOREIGN KEY (addressbook_id, group_id)  
    REFERENCES Group(addressbook, id)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your E-R (Entity-Relationship) model, the entities *Group* and *Contact* are (or should be) "dependent entities", which is to say that the existence of a *Group* or *Contact* is predicated upon that of 1 or more other entities, in this case *AddressBook*, that contributes to the **identity** of the dependent entity. The primary key of a dependent entity is composite and includes foreign keys to the entity(ies) upon which it is dependent.

The primary key of both Contact and Group include the primary key of the AddressBook to which they belong. Once you do that, everything falls into place:

```
create table Address
(
  id int not null ,
  ... ,

  primary key (id) ,
)

create table Contact
(
  address_book_id int not null ,
  id              int not null ,
  ... ,

  primary key ( address_book_id , id ) ,
  foreign key ( address_book_id      ) references AddressBook ( id ) ,
)

create table Group
(
  address_book_id int not null ,
  id              int not null ,
  ... ,

  primary key ( address_book_id , id ) ,
  foreign key ( address_book_id      ) references AddressBook( id ) ,
)

create table GroupContact
(
  address_book_id int not null ,
  contact_id      int not null ,
  group_id        int not null ,

  primary key ( address_book_id , contact_id , group_id ) ,
  foreign key ( address_book_id , contact_id ) references Contact ( address_book_id , id ) ,
  foreign key ( address_book_id , group_id   ) references Group   ( address_book_id , id ) ,
)
```

Cheers.