# Mapping compound foreign key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622262/how-to-i-design-a-database-constraint-so-two-entities-can-only-have-a-many-to-man) on how to design a database schema.

In summary I have an addressbook that can contain contacts and groups.  Groups can also contain contacts, but only contacts which are in the same addressbook as them.

**Addressbook**

Addressbook id

**Contact**

id

Addressbook id

**Group**

id

Group id

**Group To Contact**

id

Addressbook id

Contact id

Group id

By adding addressbook id to the many to many relationship table, I can enforce that the addressbooks match.  I am however relatively new to hibernate, so:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "Contact")
  public class Contact 
  {
    Addressbook addressbook;

    //----bidirectional association
    private List groups = new ArrayList();
    //----
  }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "Group")
  public class Group 
  {
    Addressbook addressbook;
    //----bidirectional association
    private List contacts = new ArrayList();
    //----
  }
```

So at a starting point, I would have the above two tables, and I would need the collections to be controlled by hibernate in a way which would enforce that the addressbook id's match when adding, or modifying objects within the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify type of elements in collection and add annotation ManyToMany

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "Contact")
  public class Contact 
  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(GenerationType=AUTO)
    private Integer contact_id;

    Addressbook addressbook;

    //----bidirectional association
    //@ManyToMany
    //private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<Group>();
    //----
  }
```

And I think, there is no need to add collection groups to Contact. You can select groups by contact id from Groups table. Also, you need to add id's to each table.

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "Group")
  public class Group 
  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(GenerationType=AUTO)
    private Integer group_id;

    Addressbook addressbook;
    //----bidirectional association
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    //----
  }
```

Comment: This does not enforce contacts and groups to contain the same addressbook or am I missing something.  Surely I want collections at both ends?  Ie, from a contact get all it's groups, or from a group get all it's contacts?

Comment: Then you have to do next way: Contacts can be only inside groups (if group is not specified - contact places in UNCATEGORIZED group, which is default in every AddressBook). Then group has only one parent AddressBook.

Comment: That would not work, I need a many to many relationship between contacts and groups.  In my system contacts will not be in groups most of the time.  Your solution also still means it is possible to add contacts to groups even if the contact belongs to a different addressbook.